# change border color of multiple divs with button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm totally new to this and working on a script that will change body background color and some html div's border color on button click.

I got where I can change the body background color to a random color with button click but now I'm stuck on how to do the same to all div borders with a separate button and all the divs have different class names and I would like to change them all at same time to same random color.

Any ideas that will help me or if you could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

```js
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
var allchar = "0123456789ABCDEF";

button2.addEventListener("click", myFun);

function myFun() {
  var randcol = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    randcol += allchar[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + randcol;
}
```

```css
.hud-menu-1 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: red;
}

.hud-menu-2 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: red;
}

.hud-menu-3 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: red;
}

.hud-menu-4 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: red;
}

.hud-menu-5 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="hud-menu-1" style="text-align:center">
  Text Here
</div>
<br>

<div class="hud-menu-2" style="text-align:center">
  Text Here
</div>
<br>

<div class="hud-menu-3" style="text-align:center">
  Text Here
</div>
<br>

<div class="hud-menu-4" style="text-align:center">
  Text Here
</div>
<br>

<div class="hud-menu-5" style="text-align:center">
  Text Here
</div>
<br>

<button id="button1">click me to change border color</button>
<button id="button2">click me to change background color</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a separate function and attach a click event to the `button1` then inside the function get all the divs using `querySelectorAll` and loop through them changing the border like :

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^=hud-menu]');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].style.borderColor = "#" + randcol
}
```

```js
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

var allchar = "0123456789ABCDEF";

button1.addEventListener("click", changeBorderColor);
button2.addEventListener("click", myFun);

function changeBorderColor() {
  var randcol = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    randcol += allchar[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }

  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^=hud-menu]');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].style.borderColor = "#" + randcol
  }
}

function myFun() {
  var randcol = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    randcol += allchar[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + randcol;
}
```

```css
.hud-menu-1,
.hud-menu-2,
.hud-menu-3,
.hud-menu-4,
.hud-menu-5 {
  border: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="hud-menu-1" style="text-align:center">
  Text Here
</div>
<br>

<div class="hud-menu-2" style="text-align:center">
  Text Here
</div>
<br>

<div class="hud-menu-3" style="text-align:center">
  Text Here
</div>
<br>

<div class="hud-menu-4" style="text-align:center">
  Text Here
</div>
<br>

<div class="hud-menu-5" style="text-align:center">
  Text Here
</div>
<br>

<button id="button1">click me to change border color</button>
<button id="button2">click me to change background color</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use code as below:

```
        document.getElementsByClassName("hud-menu-"+i)[0].style.borderColor = "#" + randcol;
```

Here:

```js
    var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
    var allchar = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    button2.addEventListener("click", myFun);

    function myFun() {
      var randcol = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        randcol += allchar[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
      }
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + randcol;
    }
function changeBorder(){
      var randcol = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        randcol += allchar[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
      }
      for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("hud-menu-"+i)[0].style.borderColor = "#" + randcol;
      }
}
```

```css
.hud-menu-1 {
      border-style: solid;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border-color: red;
    }

    .hud-menu-2 {
      border-style: solid;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border-color: red;
    }

    .hud-menu-3 {
      border-style: solid;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border-color: red;
    }

    .hud-menu-4 {
      border-style: solid;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border-color: red;
    }

    .hud-menu-5 {
      border-style: solid;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="hud-menu-1" style="text-align:center">
      Text Here
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="hud-menu-2" style="text-align:center">
      Text Here
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="hud-menu-3" style="text-align:center">
      Text Here
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="hud-menu-4" style="text-align:center">
      Text Here
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="hud-menu-5" style="text-align:center">
      Text Here
    </div>
    <br>

    <button id="button1" onclick="changeBorder()">click me to change border color</button>
    <button id="button2">click me to change background color</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getElementsByTagName()` if you really want to change **all** `div` elements. For more complex sites you may want to use `getElementsByClassName()` instead, as @לבנימלכה pointed out.

Notice that you don't need to bind your function with js. You can add it to the button directly.

```js
function setDivBorderColor() {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divs[i].style.borderColor = 'red'; // Use random color here
    }
}
```

```css
* { 
  margin: 0.2em;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

div {
  border: solid 2px black;
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>

<!-- You can bind your function directly without js -->
<button onClick="setDivBorderColor()">Change Color</button>
```

Comment: imagine a senario that the OP has another divs on screen they change also color...??You must be specific what you want to change style

Comment: @לבנימלכה, yes. Then `getElementsByClassName()` is the better solution. He asks to change the border color of all divs. For a small project this could be the simpler solution. I'll add a disclaimer though.